# Traffic on MapView is not an Overlay

Tags: android, overlay, android-mapview, traffic

After getting the list of overlays of my map I saw that the traffic option on MapView is not a separate overlay. Is there a way to get just this layer? and manipulate it?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to get just this layer?

It is not a layer. It is a set of map tiles, just as are the regular map tiles and the satellite mode map tiles.

> and manipulate it?

No, sorry.

Comment: Do you know any web services or rss for the traffic?
I saw the Yahoo web services, but they are going to close on September. Or the Navteq services, but I' m not sure if they are free.

Comment: @Marco Calì: I have never done research in this area, and I do not know of any off the top of my head. Sorry!